# How to evaluate solid angle subtended by an ellipse at any arbitrary point on the vertical axis passing through the center

Tags: differential-geometry

`Question: How to evaluate the exact value of solid angle subtended by an ellipse (or elliptical plane) at any arbitrary point lying on the vertical axis passing through the center.

Standard equation of the ellipse centered at the origin in XY-plane is given as 
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac {y^2}{b^2} =1$$or$$y^2=\frac{b^2}{a^2}  \left(a^2-x^2 \right)$$  or  $$y=\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2 }=f(x)$$

We know from a Corollary of Solid Geometry that the solid angle (ω) subtended by any plane bounded by the curve y=f(x) & the co-ordinate axes x=0,y=0 in the first quadrant at any point P(0,0,h) is given as

$$ω=∫_0^φ\frac{f(htanφ)dφ}{\sqrt{(f(htanφ))^2+h^2 sec^2 φ}}$$
    $∀ h=constant$ and  $0≤φ≤π/2$

Since, an origin centered ellipse is divided into four symmetrical parts corresponding to four quadrants in XY plane, hence the solid angle covered by an origin centered ellipse at any point  P(0,0,h) lying on the vertical axis (Z-axis) passing through the center (origin O) of the plane is given as

$$ω=4∫_0^φ\frac{f(htanφ)dφ}{\sqrt{(f(htanφ))^2+h^2 sec^2 φ}}$$

$$=4∫_0^α\frac{\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-(htanφ)^2 }dφ}{\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}\left(a^2-(htanφ)^2\right)^2+h^2 sec^2 φ}}$$

$$where, α=tan^{-1}\frac {a}{h}$$
$$=4∫_0^α\frac{b\sqrt{a^2-h^2 tan^2 φ}  dφ}{\sqrt{a^2 b^2-b^2 h^2 tan^2 φ+a^2 h^2 sec^2 φ}}$$

$$=4∫_0^α\frac{bh\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{h}\right)^2-tan^2 φ}  dφ}{\sqrt{a^2 (b^2+h^2 )+h^2 (a^2-b^2 ) tan^2 φ}}$$

$$=\frac{4ab}{h\sqrt{b^2+h^2 }}∫_0^\frac{π}{2}cos^2 θ \left(1+\frac{a^2}{h^2}  sin^2 θ\right)^{-1} \left(1+\frac{(a^2-b^2 ) sin^2 θ}{b^2+h^2 } \right)^{\frac{-1}{2}} dθ$$
$$∀  h>a≥b>0$$

Although, by applying condition h>a≥b>0  & using binomial expansion & beta-function, we can evaluate the above value of solid angle (ω) based on the approximation in binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{-n}\approx1-nx$    $∀ |x|<1$

$$ω≈πab\left[\frac{4(4h^2-a^2 )(b^2+h^2 )-(2h^2-a^2 )(a^2-b^2 )}{16h^3 (b^2+h^2 )^\frac 32 }\right]$$
 $$ ∀  h>a≥b>0$$
`

This value is an approximate value so it may have certain error & I suspect for an analytic formula to be derived/obtained to evaluate the exact value of solid angle subtended by an ellipse (at any point lying on the vertical axis passing through the center) by using analytic formula. Although I had already derived a formula to calculate the approximate value of solid angle subtended by an ellipse but the exact evaluation of solid angle is still to be done through further investigation on this topic either by evaluating the above (likely to be insolvable) integration if possible or by any other method in Solid Geometry.

Answer (score 1):

In a spherical coordinate system centered at the observer, with
polar angle $\theta$ ($0\le \theta \le \pi$) and azimuth angle
$\varphi$ ($0\le \varphi \le 2\pi$) the solid angle of the object
is the double integral
\begin{equation}
\Omega = \int \sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\varphi,
\end{equation}
where the two angular coordinates scan the surface of the object.
We transform the Cartesian coordinates to
spherical coordinates and perform the double integral, using the generic
\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& r \sin\theta \cos\varphi, \\
y &=& r \sin\theta \sin\varphi, \\
z &=& r \cos\theta,
\end{eqnarray}
and the inverse transformation
\begin{equation}
\varphi = \arctan\frac{y}{x},\quad \theta =\arccos \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}.
\end{equation}

The solid angle of an on-axis planar ellipse
\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} \le 1;\quad z=h
\end{equation}
with semiaxes $a$ and $b$ at distance $h$ to the observer is 4 times the solid angle of
the face in one of the octants:
\begin{equation}
\Omega =4 \iint_{x,y,\ge 0, x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2\le 1} \sin \theta d\theta d\varphi.
\end{equation}
As the outer integral we select $d\varphi$, so we need to find the upper limit of the $\theta$-coordinate
for a fixed $\varphi$. From the ratio of the equations above we have
\begin{equation}
y=x \tan\varphi
\end{equation}
and plugging this into the equation above we have *on* the edge of the ellipse
\begin{equation}
x^2\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{\tan^2\varphi}{b^2}\right)=1;
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x^2+y^2=x^2(1+\tan^2 \varphi)
=\frac{x^2}{\cos^2\varphi}
=\frac{1}{\cos^2\varphi(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{\tan^2\varphi}{b^2})}
=\frac{1}{\frac{\cos^2\varphi}{a^2}+\frac{\sin^2\varphi}{b^2}}.
\end{equation}
Using the equation above the solid angle is
\begin{equation}
\Omega =4 \int_0^{\pi/2}d\varphi \int_0^{\arccos\frac{h}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{\cos^2\varphi}{a^2}+\frac{\sin^2\varphi}{b^2}}+h^2}}} \sin \theta d\theta.
\end{equation}
Introducing the dimensionless
\begin{equation}
\alpha \equiv a/h;\quad \beta\equiv b/h,\quad \xi=b/a\le 1,
\end{equation}
the substitution $\cos\theta=t$ gives a simple first integral
\begin{eqnarray}
\Omega
&=&4 \int_0^{\pi/2}d\varphi \int_0^{\arccos\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\frac{\cos^2\varphi}{\alpha^2}+\frac{\sin^2\varphi}{\beta^2}}}}} \sin \theta d\theta
=4 \int_0^{\pi/2} \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\frac{\cos^2\varphi}{\alpha^2}+\frac{\sin^2\varphi}{\beta^2}}}} \right)
d\varphi
\nonumber \\
&=& 2\pi - 4 \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\frac{\cos^2\varphi}{\alpha^2}+\frac{\sin^2\varphi}{\beta^2}}}}d\varphi
=
2\pi-\bar \Omega
.
\end{eqnarray}
The complementary solid angle is
\begin{equation}
\bar\Omega \equiv 4 \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\frac{\cos^2\varphi}{\alpha^2}+\frac{\sin^2\varphi}{\beta^2}}}}d\varphi 
=
4\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\frac{1-u^2}{\alpha^2}+\frac{u^2}{\beta^2}}}}du
=
\nonumber
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
4\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\alpha^2\beta^2}{\beta^2(1-u^2)+\alpha^2 u^2}}}du
=
4\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\beta^2(1-u^2)+\alpha^2u^2+\alpha^2\beta^2}{\beta^2(1-u^2)+\alpha^2 u^2}}}du
=
4\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \sqrt{\frac{
\beta^2(1-u^2)+\alpha^2 u^2
}
{
\beta^2(1-u^2)+\alpha^2u^2+\alpha^2\beta^2
}
}du
\nonumber
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
4\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \sqrt{\frac{
\xi^2(1-u^2)+ u^2
}
{
\xi^2(1-u^2)+u^2+\beta^2
}
}du
=
4\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \sqrt{\frac{
\xi^2+ (1-\xi^2)u^2
}
{
\xi^2+\beta^2+(1-\xi^2)u^2
}
}du
=
2 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v}} \sqrt{\frac{
\xi^2+ (1-\xi^2)v
}
{
\xi^2+\beta^2+(1-\xi^2)v
}
}dv
\nonumber
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
2 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v}} \sqrt{\frac{
\frac{\xi^2}{1-\xi^2}+ v
}
{
\frac{\xi^2+\beta^2}{1-\xi^2}+v
}
}dv
.
\end{equation}

The using equation 256.02 in the book by Byrd and Friedman, Handbook of Elliptical Integrals for engineers and physicists (Springer, 1971) this is a complete elliptic integral of the third kind with parameter,
$k^2
=\frac{\beta^2(1-\xi^2)}{\beta^2+\xi^2}$:
\begin{equation}
\bar \Omega
=
4\frac{\xi^2}{\sqrt{\xi^2+\beta^2}} \Pi(\pi/2,1-\xi^2,k)
\end{equation}
With the aid of equations 412.01 or 413.01 by Byrd-Friedman
this could also be written as a linear combination of products
of Elliptic Integrals of the First and Second Kind.
In the limit $\xi\to 1$, $\Pi(\pi/0,0,0)\to \pi/2$, $\bar\Omega\to \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1+\beta^2}}$, the equation reduces to the well-known equation for the solid angle of the spherical cap.
This result has already been published by Conway in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nima.2009.11.075

Comment: This calculation is know included in an appendix in https://vixra.org/abs/2001.0603 .